# Clutching function for $S^n$: why a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

On [Page 22 of Hatcher's $K$ Theory](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf)  we make the following construction

> For $n,k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{ 0\}$.  Let $f:S^{k-1} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb R)$ be a continuous map. Define 
>       $$E_f:= (D_{-}^k \times \mathbb R^n \sqcup D_+^k \times \mathbb  R^n ) / \sim $$ 
>    where $\sim$ is equivalence relation generated by $(x,v) \sim (x, f(x)v)$  for $x \in D^k_{-} \cap D^k_+$.

From the map induced from projection $\pi:E_f \rightarrow S^k$, Hatcher claims this is a vector bundle. I don't understand his argument for the local trivialzation condition.

He says this is seen by

> taking an equivalent in definition... a product $S^{k-1} \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ with the map $f$...

May someone elaborate this in detail?

Comment: It's defined to be locally trivial. On the upper and lower hemispheres it's literally $D^k \times \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The local triviality i don't understand is at the equator. Ok, so I guess what he means is we stretch the sphere in the equator? And apply the above identification, but by this construction you varied the base space, and there is some details fill in?

Comment: The equator is included in BOTH discs. So it's already dealt with.

Comment: This is probably not convincing if you weren't already convinced so I will write an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially misunderstood the notation $D^k_+$ and $D^k_-$. The problem is that these are closed sets, and the definition of local triviality involves open sets. Hatcher prefers to use this definition so the 'clutching function' is only defined on the equator, not a larger (but homotopy equivalent!) set.

Instead, take $D^k_+$ to mean an open set in the $n$-sphere including the north hemisphere and a band including the equator. In fact, you might as well just say "Let $D^k_+$ mean everything except the south pole." So let's do that. Similarly for $D^k_-$: define it as the sphere minus the north pole. Then their intersection is $S^k \setminus \{N, S\} \cong S^k \times \Bbb R \simeq S^{k-1}$. We choose a function $f: S^k \setminus \{N, S\} \to GL_n(\Bbb R)$ to serve as the transition function.

Now the formula for $E_f$ is identical to the formula you gave, and (tautologically) $E_f$ has canonical trivializations over $S^k \setminus \{N\}$ and $S^k \setminus \{S\}$.

---

If the question is why this is equivalent to the previous definition: Choose $f': S^{k-1} \to GL_n(\Bbb R)$ to be the restriction of $f$ above to the equator. There is a map $E_{f'} \to E_{f}$ given by sending (north hemisphere) x $\Bbb R^n$ to the corresponding subset in $D^n_+ \times \Bbb R^n$, and similarly for the southern hemisphere; these agree on the overlap (the equator) precisely because $f' = f|_{S^{k-1}}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand your point now, I will have to write this out in detail. But is not there one more step? You need to show that any map $f':S^{k-1} \rightarrow GL_n (\mathbb{R})$ is the restriction of some map $f:S^k \setminus \{N,S\} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @CyrylL $S^k \setminus \{N, S\} \cong S^{k-1} \times \Bbb R$ by stereographic projection, as mentioned in the answer. I hope I do not need to prove that any map from $S^{k-1}$ extends to one from $S^{k-1} \times \Bbb R$. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, I have added a solution post below to spell out the equivalence. Please do correct me if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I will show how we can pull a trivilization from an extension to the original definition. Given $f:S^{k-1} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb R)$, let $r: S^n \setminus \{N,S\} \rightarrow S^{n-1}$ be a retraction.

Then this induces a map $f':S^n \setminus \{N,S\} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $$f'(x)=f(r(x)), \quad \quad (*)$$ 
Let us denote $\hat{E}_f$ as the bundle induced from $f'$, which Mike Miller has proven above.

---

There are trivial inclusions, 
$$D^n_- \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow S^n \setminus \{ N\} \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \hat{E}_f,  $$
$$D^n_+ \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow S^n \setminus \{S\} \times \mathbb R^n  \rightarrow \hat{E}_f $$ 
 and under quotient relation, inducing 
$$ i: E_f \rightarrow \hat{E}_f$$

Note that there are retractions $S^n \setminus \{ S \} \rightarrow  D^n_+$. Thus, this induces map
$$ S^n \setminus \{ S\} \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow D^n_+ \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow E_f $$

A similar map for the sphere with north pole taken induces 
$$ i: S^n \setminus \{S \} \times \mathbb R^n \sqcup S^n \setminus \{N \} \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow E_f. $$ 
 now note that the points $(x,v), (x,f'(x)^{-1}v)$ gets identified for $x \notin S^{n-1}$, by $(*)$. 
$$ (x,v) \mapsto (r(x),v) \mapsto [r(x),v]$$ 
$$ (x,f'(x)^{-1}v) \mapsto (r(x),f'(x)^{-1}v) \mapsto [r(x), f(r(x))f'(x)^{-1}v] = [r(x),v]$$ 
 Thus, this induces a continuous map 
$$ i^{-1}:E_{f'} \rightarrow E_f $$ 
 which by element chase, can be seen to be a clear inverse of $E_f$. As the map is linear on each fiber, we can utilize the localization in $\hat{E}_f$ for that of $E_f$.